# Data summarizing based on values in column

Tags: linux, text-files, summary

I want to parse a text file containing four columns, as follows:

```
a  343  rty  awdr     
a  345  rty  awdr   
a  386  rty  bfggd   
b  390  rty  bfggd  
b  396  rty  45fggd   
b  400  rty  45fggd  
b  415  rty  45fggd
```

The goal is to count how many times a specific value is repeated in column 4 and write an output like this in two columns:

```
awdr     2   
bfggd    2   
45fggd   3
```

Comment: awk {print $4 } | sort | uniq –c

Comment: I edited this post in the `Help and Improvement` section of the review queue, but without sufficient information, this question is near unsalvageable. Where are you printing this file out to? A file or console? What format is this file in? **Most importantly, what have you tried?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with awk:

```
$cat test.txt | awk '{tbl[$4]++;} END { for (s in tbl) printf("%s %d\n", s, tbl[s]);}'
awdr 2
bfggd 2
45fggd 3
```